# reading two long sentences using scanf

Tags: c, string, scanf

I want to read two long sentences from input using `scanf()` which are in two new lines.

**Code:**

```
int main() {
    char a[100], b[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]s", a);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", b);
    printf("%s\n%s", a, b);
}
```

**Input:**

```
she is beautiful
That is a flower
```

**Output:**

```
she is beautiful
```

The second input is not being read by the `scanf()` statement.

**How to fix it?**

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` --> `"%99[^\n]%*c"`

Comment: Change this `scanf("%[^\n]s",a);` to `scanf(" %s",a);`

Comment: `scanf()` is not very easy to use, maybe you should try `fgets()` or `getline()` (non standard :sick:).

Comment: Why do you want `scanf` instead of e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)?

Comment: If you insist on `scanf()`, @BLUEPIXY has the *correct* format string for you, but it should be explained in an answer. Nevertheless, `fgets()` would be the better function for the job.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That version will fail if input starts with newline

Comment: @H.Figueiredo that will fail to read the OP's strings

Comment: @Meenakshiyegu Is there a blank line between _two long sentences_?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY No there is no blank line between two sentence

Answer (score 5):

This needs a *correct* answer. If you *insist* on using `scanf()`, there's only one format string that is *safe* and will do what you want:

```
int main() {
    char a[100] = "";
    char b[100] = "";
    scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", a);
    scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", b);
    printf("%s\n%s", a, b);
}
```

In your original string, you had `[^\n]s` which is wrong, because `[^\n]` is a conversion specifier itself, matching anything except a newline. So there shouldn't be an `s` following it.

The next change is the `99` prepended. This ensures a maximum of `99` characters is converted -- plus one byte for the terminating `0`, you have exactly the 100 characters available in your array. Without that, if the user enters more than 99 characters, your buffer would overflow.

The last change is to append `%*c`: `%c` will match any character, in this case the newline that is left after matching `%[^\n]`. But you're not interested in it, you just want to consume it. This is what the `*` is for, it discards the result of the matching.

---

If you can, just use `fgets()` like this, it is much simpler to use for this case:

```
int main() {
    char a[100] = "";
    char b[100] = "";
    fgets(a, 100, stdin);
    fgets(b, 100, stdin);

    // if needed, strip newlines, e.g. like this:
    size_t n = strlen(a);
    if (n && a[n-1] == '\n') a[--n] = 0;
    n = strlen(b);
    if (n && b[n-1] == '\n') b[--n] = 0;


    printf("%s\n%s", a, b);
}
```

Comment: What if there is a buffer overflow? The user inputs a string greater that 100

Comment: @VidorVistrom I think it's explained in my answer regarding `scanf()` and for `fgets()`, that's what the second parameter is for.

Comment: If a user inputs a value greater than 100 chars, it will automatically allocate it to the other variable.. 100 is for first variable. If 100 is exceeded including the null, the other variable will get the exceeding chars

Comment: input this to your program aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: @VidorVistrom that would probably make a nice question. What you see as a result is not a *buffer overflow*, but the second call to `scanf()` or `fgets()` continuing to read where the first call stopped because there was no newline inside the limit of bytes to be read. For a robust program, you'd have to check whether you really have read a full line. This is possible, but outside the scope of *this* question.

Comment: Yes, this will happen. @VidorVistrom just so you can understand, here's a [version checking whether the line was complete](https://ideone.com/Cwjzg1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146046/discussion-between-vidor-vistrom-and-felix-palmen).

Comment: `scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", a);` is a problem if the first character read is a `'\n'`.  `a` is not updated, `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.  Also a problem with end-of-file and rare input error.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `fgets`. And this could work for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    char a[100], b[100];

    if (fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin) == NULL) {
        puts("fgets error");
        return -1;
    }

    if (fgets(b, sizeof b, stdin) == NULL) {   //Read blank lines 
        puts("fgets error");
        return -1;
    }

    if (fgets(b, sizeof b, stdin) == NULL) {
        puts("fgets error");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("%s\n%s", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP is ambiguous about the input forget What I said about that you can remove your third call to fgets(). return `-1` in main is strange better to return `1`

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks for your advice. I have modified my answer.

Comment: @YunbinLiu printf("%s%s",a,b); prints two sentence in new line without a '\n' so does fgets read '\n' as a character

Comment: @Meenakshiyegu Thanks for your advice. But it depends on the output format you want.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this

```
int main(){

    char a[100];

    while (scanf("%[^\n]%*c", a)==1) {
     printf("%s\n",a); 
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't work: https://ideone.com/x8k4XM, buffer overflow vulnerability.

Comment: need to put another enter to get next line - try it. I

Comment: If first character is a `'\n'`, nothing is printed.

Comment: \n is newline. If first character is \n then first line does not contain anything.